# code not executing trying to count how many times each letter appears in a piece of text

Tags: python, dictionary, pydictionary

I'm trying to count how many times each letter appears in a piece of text.

```
def  count_letters(text):
    result = {}
    for letter in text:
        if letter not in result:
            result[letter]= 0
            result[letter] += 1
    return result
    
count_letters("aaad g a")
```

When I type this code however, it's only showing 1 as the values for each key. I was expecting 4 for a, 1 for d, etc

Answer (score 2):

Your indentation is off; you only increment the count the first time you see the letter.

```
def count_letters(text):
    result = {}
    for letter in text:
        if letter not in result:
            result[letter] = 0
        result[letter] += 1  # This must not happen only when you've not seen that letter yet, but each time
    return result
 
print(count_letters("aaad g a"))
```

This prints:

> {'a': 4, 'd': 1, ' ': 2, 'g': 1}

Or maybe this version of the code is clearer?

```
def count_letters(text):
    result = {}
    for letter in text:
        if letter not in result:
            result[letter] = 1
        else:
            result[letter] += 1
    return result
 
print(count_letters("aaad g a"))
```

This sets the hash value to 1 the first time you see that letter, or increases the count every other time.

Answer (score 2):

The `result[letter] += 1` statement is indented to be under the `if` statement, so it will be only be executed the first time a letter is seen. Change the indentation level to be directly inside the `for` instead.

```py
if letter not in result:
    result[letter] = 0
result[letter] += 1
```

A simpler method would be to use `collections.defaultdict`, which obviates the need to manually set the value to `0` on the first occurrence.

```py
from collections import defaultdict
result = defaultdict(int)
for letter in text:
    result[letter] += 1
return result
```

Or even better, just use `collections.Counter`.

```
from collections import Counter
return Counter(text)
# or {**Counter(text)} to get a regular dict
```